# Tibco Spotfire Desktop. Trusting Custom queries ruins the filters

Tags: oracle, filter, spotfire, tibco

I am using spotfire desktop for analysing data in an Oracle database. I would like to share the visualizations I am developing. I have seen that the custom queries must be trusted by other users. Below is the solution that I found by browsing the internet. The solution below allows other users to retreive the data, however, afetr doing this the filters do not work anymore and need to be manually reset. Can anyone help with this problem?
Thank you

*If it is saved as part of a report
Open the report in the TIBCO Spotfire (Analyst / Desktop / Professional) client.
Go to the top menu and choose Edit -> Data Connection properties .
Highlight the connection and press the "Settings" button.
On the "General" tab, click the "Edit" button.
Highlight your custom query and choose "Edit custom query" from the menu right above it.
Press the "Verify" button, then the "OK" button.
Press OK all the way until the Data Connection Properties dialogue window is closed.*

Comment: I haven't researched your issue, but is there anything preventing you from using the Information Library/Designer to import your data? Data Connections are useful but I think you will always run into stuff like this using them. Information Library is closer aligned with best practices, but I know it's not always possible to use. have you considered using the Library instead of Connections?

Comment: Presently we only have a few individual desktop licenses and as far as I understood (coorect me if I am mistaken) the Library is only avilable for Server licenses that is why we are not using it.